# How can I run Redis in the background?

Tags: redis

I need Redis running while I work on a particular codebase. I often open a new terminal and run it there. How can I run it in the background?

Comment: wow! how could you ask and answer question at same fraction of time "12:25:06z" ?

Comment: I think he is using SO more as a way to keep track of the small things he struggled with, not in order to actually ask questions. I think it's great, this way the next person having this problem can find the answer more quickly and just move on. I should do this too. Thanks Nathan for sharing!

Comment: @VedantKekan When asking the question, I checked the box "Answer your own question" at the bottom, which has a link to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ beside it. Patrick is correct about my intention in this case. If I search the web for an answer and don't find it quickly, I often figure it out, then come here and make a Q&A that I'll find more quickly next time, and which benefits other with the same question.

Comment: @NathanLong brilliant sir, thank for that knowledge

Answer (score 48):

Or run the following

`/usr/local/bin/redis-server --daemonize yes`

Answer (score 35):

## Use `redis-server &`

On Linus or OSX, an easy way to run a process in the background is to [follow the command with `&`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line).

You can see that it's still running with `ps -ef | grep redis` (or `pgrep redis-server`) and stop it with `pkill redis-server`.

Comment: The limitation of this approach is that you can't run the second command in the same bash command after the '&', i.e, you can't run `redis-server& && do-something-else-that-needs-redis`

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old question but I am answering just for the reference.

You need to set `daemonize yes` from `daemonize no` in your redis.conf

Reference: https://blog.art-coder.com/2011/12/01/how-to-run-redis-server-as-daemon/